# Visual Studio Code - Flutter : "Device emulator-5554 is offline"

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I have just spent an hour reading through similar questions on Stack Overflow, and they are all for Android Studio, not Visual Studio Code. Also, I am doing Flutter development, so don't have access to `adb` commands, such as `adb kill-server`.

Everything was fine, unlike I clicked the power button on my emulated Android. Now, when I `run/start debug` and `select active device`, I get `Failed to launch Nexus 5X API 29 x86: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds`.

How can I restart the emulated device? When it appears, clicking the power button does not seem to do anything. Is there a flutter terminal command?

Or can I somehow use a different emulator (if so, how)?

Comment: Please try Genymotion, It works amazingly with VS Code.

Comment: That costs 5 cents per minute - why would I want to pay that?.  Also, are you associated with them?

Comment: I use Personal Eddition, its free. Initially I tried Android Studio virtual device and Memu emulator but they were giving me same issue. So switched to Genymotion. And no, I am not associated with them apart from being user.

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice a free version, I will certainly give it a try +1  :-)

Comment: Also don't forget to install GAPPS bundle, it will be required to run apps requiring Google Play services.

Comment: Is there a fr desktop version? Can you post a URL? Also, consider posting an answer.

Comment: added  details in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue with Android Virtual Device and Memu emulator so I switched to Genymotion.

I am using Genymotion personal edition which works amazingly and it's very light on resources too as compared to AVD and Memu.

You can download Genymotion Personal edition from [Genymotion Personal Edition](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)

Apart from Installing emulator Image you should also consider installing the GAPPS bundle in the emulator as it does not comes with it preinstalled. GAPPS will be needed in many apps requiring Google Play Services.

Here are the docs on how to install GAPPS in Genymotion emulator: [GAAPS Docs](https://docs.genymotion.com/paas/7.0/07_Installing_OpenGApps.html#from-the-open-gapps-website)

[GAAPS Website](https://opengapps.org)

My Genymotion Emulator is Google Pixel 3a, 9.0 API 28.